# what is "|" in Ubuntu or Linux in general

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command

example :

```
diskFreeSpace="$(df | grep -v -E 'Filesystem|udev|tmpfs|Home|/dev/sr1|/dev/sr0' | awk '{ print $5-1+1}')"
```

and hope if you understand what is this command u help me

Comment: But some of those `|` (called "pipes") are in a regular expression, so see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the symbol is called a "pipe".

The command `df | grep` is "piping" (redirecting) the standard output of the `df` command into the standard input of the `grep` command. In this example the grep command filters the output of the df command. Then the `awk` commands is for display/format purposes.

Inside the regular expression it is specific to the grep syntax since it is surrounded by quotes it is only considered as an argument passed to `grep`

Comment: thanks bro it was useful

Comment: @mo.khashab Happy to help. For further reading, jonrsharpe gave useful links in the comment section.